# Make slider work automatically

Tags: javascript, html, slider

First of all I have no knowledge of JS. And i need to make the slider run automatically which only goes to next slide on click. So any help will be appreciable.

> HTML file

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div id="slider">
    <div id="slide-wrapper"> 
      <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
      <figure id="slide-1"><a class="view" href="#"><img src="images/demo/slider/sdslider-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>Nullamlacus dui ipsum</h2>
          <p>Attincidunt vel nam a maurisus lacinia consectetus magnisl sed ac morbi. Inmaurisus habitur pretium eu et ac vest penatibus id lacus parturpis.</p>
          <p class="right"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure id="slide-2"><a class="view" href="#"><img src="images/demo/slider/s2.png" alt=""></a>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>Aliquatjusto quisque nam</h2>
          <p>Attincidunt vel nam a maurisus lacinia consectetus magnisl sed ac morbi. Inmaurisus habitur pretium eu et ac vest penatibus id lacus parturpis.</p>
          <p class="right"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure id="slide-3"><a class="view" href="#"><img src="images/demo/slider/s3.png" alt=""></a>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>Aliquatjusto quisque nam</h2>
          <p>Attincidunt vel nam a maurisus lacinia consectetus magnisl sed ac morbi. Inmaurisus habitur pretium eu et ac vest penatibus id lacus parturpis.</p>
          <p class="right"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure id="slide-4"><a class="view" href="#"><img src="images/demo/slider/s4.png" alt=""></a>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>Aliquatjusto quisque nam</h2>
          <p>Attincidunt vel nam a maurisus lacinia consectetus magnisl sed ac morbi. Inmaurisus habitur pretium eu et ac vest penatibus id lacus parturpis.</p>
          <p class="right"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure id="slide-5"><a class="view" href="#"><img src="images/demo/slider/s5.png" alt=""></a>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>Dapiensociis temper donec</h2>
          <p>Attincidunt vel nam a maurisus lacinia consectetus magnisl sed ac morbi. Inmaurisus habitur pretium eu et ac vest penatibus id lacus parturpis.</p>
          <p class="right"><a href="#">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
      <ul id="slide-tabs">
        <li><a href="#slide-1">All About The University</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-2">Why You Should Study With Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-3">Education And Student Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-4">Alumni And Its Donors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-5">Latest University News &amp; Events</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- 

    ################################################################################################ --> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="section-top">
                            <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
                                <div class="title-img">
                                    <div class="title"><img src="images/book1.png" alt=""/></div>
                                        <div class="title-desc"><p>Chairman's Message</p></div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div> 
                                </div>
                                <p class="desc"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</strong></p>
                                <p class="desc1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><span>Read more</span><img src="images/more_arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
                                <div class="title-img1">
                                    <div class="title"><img src="images/cup.png" alt=""/></div>
                                        <div class="title-desc"><p>Event Calender</p></div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div> 
                                </div>                  
                                <p class="desc-middle"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</strong></p>
                                <p class="desc1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary1"><span>Read more</span><img src="images/more_arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
                                <div class="title-img2">
                                    <div class="title"><img src="images/books.png" alt=""/></div>
                                    <div class="title-desc"><p>Virtual library</p></div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div> 
                                </div>
                                <p class="last"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</strong></p>
                                <p class="desc1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary2"><span>Read more</span><img src="images/more_arrow.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

> JS code

I have seen many similar kind of questions on this site but Js code they post are way more different than mine. So this is hard to find which is the correct portion of code I need to show for help. Don't know I am providing correct code or not but after many search I found this code may be useful.

```
m.Event.prototype=    {isDefaultPrevented:bb,isPropagationStopped:bb,isImmediatePropagationStopped:bb,preventDefault:function(){var a=this.originalEvent;this.isDefaultPrevented=ab,a&&(a.preventDefault?a.preventDefault():a.returnValue=!1)},stopPropagation:function(){var a=this.originalEvent;this.isPropagationStopped=ab,a&&(a.stopPropagation&&a.stopPropagation(),a.cancelBubble=!0)},stopImmediatePropagation:function(){var a=this.originalEvent;this.isImmediatePropagationStopped=ab,a&&a.stopImmediatePropagation&&a.stopImmediatePropagation(),this.stopPropagation()}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not very clear so im going to suggest you a easy step since you have a few knowledge in JavaScript.

Use bootstrap [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Bootstrap Tabbed slider :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

         <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->


        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>


    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

The css:

```
body { padding-top: 20px; }
#myCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
    background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

The Snippet link [here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/tabbed-slider-carousel).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But can you suggest me other slider instead of this. Because i need a slider that have tabs at bottom instead of bullets. That tabs should be able to hold some text and other functionality should be like bullets in the slider. And also that should run automatically. Tabs should be at bottom.

Comment: can you show me an example? maybe an image of the slider you expect, then I can give the code for it.

Comment: Here is an example -        http://thespectrumtechnology.com/wp-content/uploads/Untitled.png

Comment: Answer is updated. Here is the link. Hope it helps, and cheers ;)

Comment: That was perfect But it uses bootstrap. So when I embed it into my web page then it disturbed my page's css because of bootstrap. My all page got messed up.

Comment: so, you dont want to use any frameworks? or is there any other frameworks your using?

Comment: I am not using any framework. Just using my own CSS. But this framework did change my page layout. My menubar and my div got messy. This framework is overriding my css.

Comment: yes, you can try this. link the bootsrap css above your css. So your css will be prioritized here. Also bootstrap is a great framework, why dont you switch to that?

Comment: okay, when you add the bootarap css, you do something like this :
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" ="anonymous"> and then add your own css. <link href="css/yourcss.css" ="anonymous">

Comment: Hey Thanks! Its worked perfectly. Your way was way too awesome. Thanks again.